# how to extract leveldb type data store (sstable + memtable) from cassandra or hbase?

Tags: open-source, cassandra, hbase, bigdata, leveldb

LevelDB is a very interesting C++ data store from Google. I am looking for something similar in the Java world (frankly so I can understand the code better, run it on windows more easily, etc.).

I understand Hbase and Cassandra also contain the same basic technology: sstable for file store, memtable for in-memory store (before it is sorted and written to disk), some sort of compression, periodic compaction, etc.

Are there any efforts to extract this technology from the larger projects? I have started looking at the code base myself (mainly Cassandra) but these are obviously not trivial projects. Which project has more modular code?

Look forward to any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that there's some general purpose, non-trivial module you could extract that's common to these 3 stores. You're right that the ideas are very similar, but the implementation (of storage file formats, in-memory representations, compactions, coordination services, etc) is sufficiently complex that trying to share code among 3 divergent projects like this would make things more complicated, not less.

Between Cassandra and HBase, in a sense, the latter has more modular code in that it delegates big parts of its functionality to other layers (HDFS, Zookeeper) whereas in Cassandra, that's all handled internal to the project. But even in HBase, this part (the physical storage formats, compaction algorithms, etc) are coupled with the overall system, not layered in.

If you're looking for an architecture that supports different storage engines, or want to see a different vision of how the layering in a distributed system might be approached, take a look also at Riak (which does support LevelDB as one of its storage layer options):

http://wiki.basho.com/LevelDB.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the link is interesting. I didn't mean to imply that I was planning on combining various modules from these three projects. I was wondering how difficult it would be to extract leveldb type functionality from either cassandra or hbase.